# Windows 10 pro and IIS concurrent request limitation

Tags: .net, iis, concurrency, python-requests

I have developed an c# web application that has an WCF service. This application is hosted in Windows 10 PRO 64x system. Everything works well so far, except from a "concurrent" requests limitation.

I performed a stress test via SOAPUI and the IIS handles only 10 concurrent requests. Is there a limitation in operation system ? Is there any way to overcome this limitation ?

Thank you very much,

*Screenshot attached below with concurrent requests

screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4q4x.png)

Comment: An old article ( [Windows 8 / IIS 8 Concurrent Requests Limit](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit)) ,but it appears to be limited based on OS License Level.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there any way to overcome this limitation ?

Comment: Q: Is there any way to overcome this limitation?  A: Yes: do your load testing on Windows Server.  Even Windows Server on a VM will give you more realistic feedback than testing on a client OS.

Comment: Although this question is rather old, here's a link to the [Windows 10 License Terms](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm) which mentions a total connection count of 20 for all concurrent network connections.