# IIS Request Count Limitation vs IIS Express - Web API Core

Tags: c#, angular, iis, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I'm writing a Web API Core project using Signal-R. There is a hub which generate a connection ID for each request:

```
public class TargetHub : Hub<ITargetLogger>
{
    public string GetConnectionId()
    {
        return Context.ConnectionId;
    }
}
```

I'm using Angular 7 in my UI side and I'm using this piece of code to create a new request:

```
  GetConnection() {
    this.projectHandle = Guid.newGuid();
    let connection: signalR.HubConnection;
    let accessToken = "3076a225-f2f6-4c68-b894-08accb62bb90";

    connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:200/targetHub", { accessTokenFactory: () => accessToken }).build();
    this.currentConnection = connection;
    connection.start().then(() => {
      connection.invoke("GetConnectionId")
        .then((connectionId) => { this.currentConnectionId = connectionId; })
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
```

When I'm debugging and testing the project on `IIS Express`, it works great. I can create as many request as I want.

But When I publish it on main `IIS`, I only can create 10 requests. What is this limitation and how to avoid and fix it?

Comment: @mjwills I just edit my last line. After publishing the project the problem will appear.

Comment: If you open the app in Chrome, IE 11, Firefox and Edge simultaneously, do they all get 10 requests each? In total? Something else?

Comment: @mjwills In total I can send 10 request in all browsers. for example 3 in IE, 4 in FireFox and 3 in Chrome. nothing more.

Comment: Windows 10? You might try Windows Server 2016/2019.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358921/windows-10-pro-and-iis-concurrent-request-limitation

Answer (score 0):

You can use kestrel:
Kestrel is a cross-platform web server for ASP.NET Core. Kestrel is the web server that's included by default in ASP.NET Core project templates. so using this you do not have request limitation.

[Kestrel's Description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0)